# Flutter Cannot resolve symbol 'embedding' and Cannot resolve symbol 'FlutterActivity'

Tags: android-studio, flutter

error shown in Flutter Android project folder in mainactivity

```
package com.malik.database_demo;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
}
```

Comment: Did you run `flutter pub get`?

Comment: flutter pub get for what ?

Comment: For `get`ing the Flutter dependencies.

Comment: Its not the dependencies issue although i have run it anyway i am in Android project folder in mainactivity and this errors always shows up

Comment: What does it look like if you run `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: all is ok and no issues found

Answer (score 31):

Currently you are probably trying to directly edit the MainActivity class from your Flutter project. (By expanding android -> Navigation to 'MainActivity.java' or 'MainActivity.kt' and editing it).

I have observed that when we try to edit the native side code this way, Flutter is not able to recognize the android part.

What you can do is open the 'android' part of your flutter project and then edit it.

To achieve this :

1. Click File -> Open -> Navigate to your current Flutter project -> Expand it and find the android part (refer the example below)

[image]

[1 = Your current Flutter project,2 = The android part of your flutter project]

2. Click on that android part and click Open. Wait for the indexing and all to complete and then I dont think it will give those errors.

GLHF :)

Comment: This is something we get from experience.Thanks, Sarvesh Bhava

Comment: yes no errors at the same current new window , but backing to the main project tab it still ask for jar file and the errors still tuned ! ,, i think it is jar issue ..

Comment: Thanks it's really helpful for someone new in flutter.

Answer (score 1):

I added flutter.jar as a library. This seemed to work.

I'm not sure if there are some unintended consequences yet!

Answer (score 0):

A little update on Servesh Dalvi's response: if you're using any of the latest  versions of android studio like Android Studio Giraffe you might want to open your android part of your flutter project like the attached screenshot shows, by clicking on the android part directory, scroll down to Flutter, and select 'open Android module in Android Studio.[image: Screenshot on opening android part of flutter project]

Answer (score 0):

What solved my problem is by navigating to the **android part of the application** as mentioned earlier in the first answer where the indexing of the gradle files was performed and then when I re opened the **project view** of the application then the error was still not resolved.
Then I run the following commands

1. **flutter clean**
2. **flutter pub get**
3. **flutter run**

And then Invalidated the caches from the

- **Menu>> File >>Invalidated caches**

and finally ***restarted the Android Studio*** and boom the error was solved there were no errors.
These were the steps that resolved my error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have updated the answer to the most simple form that it can be.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this occurred after I updated the IntelliJ IDE. None of the above solutions worked, including opening in AS and rebuilding, invalidating caches, Flutter Clean, etc. The solution for me was to delete the `android` folder from the Flutter project and then re-add the Android platform as follows:

`flutter create . --platforms=android`