# Errors during flutter app build. "Kotlin: Unresolved reference: embedding" and "Kotlin: Unresolved reference: FlutterActivity"

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, intellij-idea

As in title I'm getting errors during flutter app build. I already tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64468323/flutter-cannot-resolve-symbol-embedding-and-cannot-resolve-symbol-flutteracti)
And when I'm syncing all dependencies and all stuff in android folder I'm getting error: "Could not create task ':generateLockfiles'." I tried multiple solutions from forum and sometimes they help(sometimes because it's temporary to point when I'm creating new project with the same solutions) to the point where generate... error is not popping but still nothing changes the first error from title. I think that i don't need to put my code here because it's sample app that's created during project creating. I'm using Intellij IDEa 2022.1.2. Flutter 3.0.2. Java 11.0.5 Windows 11